# How to apply django transaction to every celery task?

Tags: python, django, transactions, celery

```py
from celery.task import Task
from django.db import transaction

class MyTask(Task):
    # ...
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # doesn't work
        with transaction.atomic():
             super().run(*args, **kwargs)

celery_task = celery_app.task(ignore_result=True, base=MyTask)

@celery_task
# @transaction.atomic  # this should work, but I want to add transaction through base task class
def foo_task():
    pass
```

I need to add an atomic transaction to every task with `celery_task` decorator without using additional decorators.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/
Use savepoint, savepoint_commit and savepoint_rollback.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override the `__call__(*args, **kwargs)` method.

```
class AtomicTask(celery.Task):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)


atomic_task = celery.task(ignore_result=True, base=AtomicTask)

@atomic_task
def update_user(user_id):
    # This code can run only inside a transaction. 
    # Otherwise, the TransactionManagementError will be raised.
    user = User.objects.select_for_update().get(pk=user_id)
    user.first_name = 'John'
    user.save()
```